# CSS selector works in Firefox but not in IE

Tags: css, firefox, selenium, internet-explorer

Does anyone know why this CSS selector works in Firefox but not in IE7 or IE8?

```
css=div[style~='visible;'] div[class~='x-combo-list-item']:contains('Test Job')
```

I'm using this in a Selenium test to find an element on the page.

Edit: The :contains selector is not the problem. I'm using it elsewhere in my tests and it works in IE6, 7, and 8.

Comment: No, just a normal CSS selector.

Comment: What version of "IE" are you using? I don't believe that IE6/7 support those 'pseudo-selectors'.

Comment: No, it's a selenium "locator". Probably using CSS to avoid the slowness of XPath...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that Selenium attempts to support all of CSS3 for *all* browsers in it's selector engine. It may be that it does not support multiple levels of the attribute selectors in IE.

You might be stuck with an XPath "locator" this one

Alternatively, you could try:

```
div[style~='visible'] .x-combo-list-item:contains('Test Job')
```

Comment: I'll look into that, thanks. Do you know if Xpath supports something similar to "~="?

Comment: Yes, //div@style[contains('text')//div@class[contains('..')]

Comment: Argh, wish I could edit comments. 

Last one should be:
//div[contains(@style,'text')]...

Comment: Word of warning, though, XPath is sloooow on IE when you use "//" queries.

Comment: For the sake of posterity: the XPath did the trick. I tried the modified CSS selector, but for whatever reason Selenium doesn't like ".class".

The working XPath version of my CSS:

   //div[contains(@style, 'visible')]//div[contains(text(),'Test Job')]

Comment: Yeah... I've definitely experienced the slowness, which is why I'm using CSS selectors wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the :contains pseduo-class is a CSS3 addition and whatever version of IE you're using (you didn't specify) probably doesn't support :contains.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#selectors

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm using :contains in a number of different places, and IE7 and IE8 both support it.